# Google drive Dredit sample app for dotnet

Tags: google-drive-api

I was following exact the same steps as described in this article to test the dotnet app.

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

My env is visual studio 2010 and IIS 7

Everything was fine. The app deployment was successful and I could see the login screen and the "allow access" dialog. However once I granted access, I saw the following error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Qiang

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Source Error:

Line 82:         {
Line 83:             StoredCredentialsDBContext db = new StoredCredentialsDBContext();
Line 84:             StoredCredentials sc = db.StoredCredentialSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
Line 85:             if (sc != null)
Line 86:             {

Source File: C:\Qiang\DrEdit\Models\Utils.cs    Line: 84

Answer (score 1):

You have to install  [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876), which is used by the Entity Framework to map model classes into database entities.